# Unity2d android detecting touches

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, 2d

How to detect touches **and long touches** on buttons in unity for android?
I have already tried this function but it returns true if i touch any place on screen:

```
bool checkTouch()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < Input.touchCount; i++)
        {
            TouchPhase tp = Input.GetTouch(i).phase;
          if(tp == TouchPhase.Began || tp == TouchPhase.Ended || tp == TouchPhase.Stationary)
            return true;  
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: if(tp == TouchPhase.Began || tp == TouchPhase.Ended || tp == TouchPhase.Stationary)  here you have it. Just put your logic in the different states and thats it. If you want buttons than use UnityEngine.UI to add a GUI Canvas and Buttons in it. No script is needed fo that just functions per button

Comment: where are you calling checkTouch?

Comment: @Lotan in the script atached to the button gameobgect

Comment: Buttons by default works with click and input touches. Check it, if you add a listener like myButtonGameObject.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(()=>{Debug.Log("Click");});

Comment: @Lotan i need to register long touch, not only click

Comment: feel free to use my package: https://github.com/Menyus777/RedFox-Smart-Button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve Buttons that allow that, is to create your own button, implementing the necessary interfaces like `IPointerDownHandler, IPointerUpHandler`.

That way you could manage how will the button act, here is an example:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class LongClickButton : MonoBehaviour, IPointerDownHandler, IPointerUpHandler
{
    private bool pointerDown;
    private float pointerDownTimer;

    [SerializeField]
    private float requiredHoldTime;    

    public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        pointerDown = true;
        Debug.Log("OnPointerDown");
    }

    public void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Reset();
        Debug.Log("OnPointerUp");
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (pointerDown)
        {
            pointerDownTimer += Time.deltaTime;
            if (pointerDownTimer >= requiredHoldTime)
            {
                //do your LongClick stuff
                Debug.Log("LongClick");
                Reset();
            }
        }
    }

    private void Reset()
    {
        pointerDown = false;
        pointerDownTimer = 0;
    }    
}
```

Remember to attach the script to a GameObject that can be `interactable`, like an `Image`.